# C - alignas not giving expected result

Tags: c

`Alignas` in C11 is not working as I am expecting. This is my code:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct A
{
    alignas(int32_t) int16_t a;
    int16_t b;
};

struct B
{
    int16_t a;
    alignas(int32_t) int16_t b;
};

struct C
{
    int16_t a;
    int32_t b;
};

struct D
{
    int32_t a;
    int16_t b;
};

int main(void)
{
    printf("%zu, %zu\n", alignof(int16_t), sizeof(int16_t));
    printf("%zu, %zu\n", alignof(int32_t), sizeof(int32_t));
    printf("%zu, %zu\n", alignof(struct A), sizeof(struct A));
    printf("%zu, %zu\n", alignof(struct B), sizeof(struct B));
    printf("%zu, %zu\n", alignof(struct C), sizeof(struct C));
    printf("%zu, %zu\n", alignof(struct D), sizeof(struct D));
}
```

Output:

```
2, 2
4, 4
4, 4
4, 8
4, 8
4, 8
```

I expected the size of all these structures to be the same. Why is `struct A` not the same size as `struct B`? Am I misunderstanding how `alignas` works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say `int16_t` requires 2-byte alignment and `int32_t` requires 4-byte alignment.

```
struct A
{
    alignas(int32_t) int16_t a;
    int16_t b;
};
```

The natural layout of this would be 2 bytes for `a`, 2 bytes for `b`, and a 2-byte alignment for the whole struct.

But `alignas(int32_t)` introduces additional constraints: `a` has to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary. This forces the whole struct to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary. But the size of `a` is still just 2 bytes, so `b` can be placed immediately afterwards with no padding, on a (4n+2)-byte boundary. After 2 bytes for `b` we're on 4n+4, i.e. on a 4-byte boundary again. This means we need no padding after `b`: We could immediately start another instance of the struct.

All in all we have a struct without padding (`sizeof (struct A)` is the sum of its members' sizes, 4) and the alignment of its first member, 4.

```
struct B
{
    int16_t a;
    alignas(int32_t) int16_t b;
};
```

Here the situation is different: `a` itself only forces 2-byte alignment. But now `b` has to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary, so the whole struct has to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary and 2 bytes of padding are inserted after `a`. So far we have 2 bytes for `a`, 2 bytes of padding, 2 bytes for `b`, which lands us on a (4n+6) (i.e. 4n+2) byte boundary. We need to reach the state we started from, so another 2 bytes of padding are inserted after `b` to make sure we end on a 4-byte boundary.

All in all, we end up with 2 + 2 bytes of padding and 2 + 2 bytes of content, making the size 8.

Answer (score 2):

You've specified that the `b` element of `B` be aligned on a 4-byte boundary.  Since `a` only requires 2 bytes, this results in 2 bytes of padding between `a` and `b`, and another 2 bytes after `b` to make the structure as a whole a multiple of 4 bytes.

For `A`, only `a` has 4 byte alignment (which is has by being at the start of the struct).  `b` has no extra alignment requirement, so is immediately after with no padding, and no padding is required at the end, either.

Answer (score -2):

The reason why they are different is

*sizeof* gives the actual size in bytes required to store the type or instance of it.

*alignof* gives you the alignment in bytes required for the largest element.